# How to clear/kill tasks to not overload CPU in WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, cpu-usage, kiosk

I am currently building a kiosk application using WPF. I have one main window and several User Control (pages). After the last page, the app will redirect to the first page to start over the entire process.
I have noticed that after running the full flow for three times, the app will crash/hang due to CPU and Memory overload.
However i solve the memory overload issue by declaring the following

```
    [DllImport("KERNEL32.DLL", EntryPoint = "SetProcessWorkingSetSize", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    internal static extern bool SetProcessWorkingSetSize(IntPtr pProcess, int dwMinimumWorkingSetSize, int dwMaximumWorkingSetSize);

    [DllImport("KERNEL32.DLL", EntryPoint = "GetCurrentProcess", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    internal static extern IntPtr GetCurrentProcess();
```

and  adding this code in the Unloaded() event.

```
        IntPtr pHandle = GetCurrentProcess();
        SetProcessWorkingSetSize(pHandle, -1, -1);
```

This code able to solve the Memory Overload issue, but the CPU overload issue is still there. Can anyone please help me with it please? What shall i add in the Unloaded() event to free the CPU?

Comment: What type of tasks are you running in the application? Can you look to do less work, reduce timer calls, or anything related?

Comment: You need to provide more details. What  CPU intensive work are you doing and how? What memory intensive work are you doing and how? Remember to release unmanaged resources after leaving each page by implementing the Dispose Pattern. Every `IDisposable` must be disposed. Alternatively reuse created resources. Check your application for memory leaks. Data binding without implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` and unsubscribed events are notorious candidates to create memory leaks. Without details there is no help possible. Obviously you got some smelly code somewhere.

Comment: i m using background worker and timer in almost every page. but i close every time

Comment: Timers and brackground workers are nice sources of memory and handle leaks.

Comment: Welcome to [Asynchronous Programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async). `BackgroundWorker` is ancient legacy class. `Timer` is not needed in 99% scenarios if you're familiar with `async/await`. Hope you're not in Framework 3.5 and Windows XP.

Comment: You should not have to resort to trimming the working set using a win32 function; it's a sign you have memory leaks that should be fixed instead.  You should focus on solving the memory leaks as that might also help with the CPU starvation.  After fixing the memory leaks you can then profile and figure out your performance problems.

Comment: @aepot Please do correct me if i am wrong. I am using timer quite a lot in my app. my app have quite a few forms (Window Forms).

 When navigated to next form, i want to display the form (UI) first and then only start whatever processes/transactions needed automatically (without user intervention). What i keep getting is that, processing always take place first and then only the form (UI)  is loaded.

So i started using a timer. After 2 second timer click, i start my processing and then i dispose my timer.

is there any better way to do this?

Comment: @WaiYanMaungOo [the better way to do this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/order-of-events-in-windows-forms) - `Form.Load` event handler, or `Form.Shown`, if you want to make something only after the `Form` was displayed. Then you can make the handler `async` if needed and start asynchronous jobs there.